# passing props to props.children in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

```
const Component1 = (props) => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('hello world');
    const ChildComponent = props.children.type;
        return (
        <div>
              <ChildComponent data={myState} />
        </div>
            )
    }
    export default Component1;
```

i want pass props from Component1 to props.children, i want to ask my this approach is right ?, i am reusing Component1 in my code and passing components to Component1 like this `<Component1><Component2 /><Component1 />` i want not pass props from App component i want pass props from Component1 to props.children.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty convoluted approach. As a rule of thumb, you should have separate components in separate files.

I am not clear about what you are trying to code, but from what I deduced, here's how I'd approach it.

I will have separate `<ChildComponent />` and `<Component1 />`.

Inside the `<Component1 />`, I will render the `<ChildComponent />`

```
import ChildComponent from "components/ChildComponent";

const Component1 = (props) => {
const [myState, setMyState] = useState('hello world');
    return <ChildComponent data={myState} />
}
export default Component1;
```

You can see clearly that `Component1` is a redundant component.

However, if `<Component1/>` acts as a HOC, you can wrap the `ChildComponent` inside of it as

```
    import ChildComponent from "components/ChildComponent";
    import Component1 from "components/Component1";
    
    const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('hello world');
        return <Component1>
<ChildComponent data={myState} />
</Component1>
    }
        export default Wrapper;
```